# how can I develop Apple Java Extensions on Windows?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

When I do multi-platform testing on Windows it gets annoying that Eclipse shows errors in the project because of the com.apple.eawt code that I have in a special Mac customization task. Worse yet, if I export a runnable jar on Windows, it won't run on mac because of the unresolved compilation problems.

What's the best way to let Windows Java and com.apple.eawt live in peace? I can't see how I would be able to spin off the code to a jar, since it requires access to lots of the program's state.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I created an updated jar to solve this problem. GitHub source [here](https://github.com/ymasory/OrangeExtensions).
It's hosted on [maven central](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/yuvimasory/orange-extensions/)

Answer (score 6):

This looks like it could be what you're after: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/AppleJavaExtensions/

> This is a pluggable jar of stub classes representing the new Apple
>   eAWT and eIO APIs for Java 1.4 on Mac OS X. The purpose of these stubs
>   is to allow for compilation of eAWT- or eIO-referencing code on
>   platforms other than Mac OS X.

Comment: Oh man what a bummer. Since it's for an old JDK it doesn't support setDockIcon() which I need for when the app is launched through Java Web Start.
But thank you for the lead!!

Answer (score 0):

Put the OS X specific code in a separate class.

In your main code, use reflection to see if one of the Apple classes are present (or a Class.forName), and if so, THEN invoke the separate class above.  I cannot remember if you can do that safely just by calling it, or you need to invoke the separate class by reflection too.

Answer (score 0):

The latest can be downloaded from http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AppleJavaExtensions, click on the "Download Sample" button at the top of the page

The latest documentation is at

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/JavaSE6_AppleExtensionsRef/api/index.html?com/apple/eawt/Application.html

Comment: As of March 2014, the documentation link gives a Page Not Found. Gotta love Apple's habit of moving stuff around. *sigh*