# Menu items become disabled in Mac when an "AlwaysOnTop" frame is showing

Tags: java, macos, swing

I have some frames that have the property alwaysOnTop set to true. If this frames are showing and the main frame shows a modal dialog, all menu items stay disabled until the application is restarted.

It looks like an apple java bug

Any thoughts of a fix?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used [`setAlwaysOnTop`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop(boolean)), but it appear to be supported on Mac OS X. You might look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186135/creating-an-offscreen-frame-in-java-or-how-to-avoid-a-blank-menu-on-a-mac-when/2188981#2188981) for an example. Also, see if the [OSXAdapter example](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/OSXAdapter/listing1.html) has the same problem.

Comment: Is OSXAdapter example available somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem, see also http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2010/Jul/msg00133.html. My workaround is to hide a non modal alwaysOnTop window, show modal Window, hide modal window restore/show again the non modal alwaysOnTop window.

I tried to reenable menuitems from java, then from ObjC side, without positive results (I could see, that MenuItems were enabled for 0.3-0.5 second or so, but went disabled by some magic again and again).

I reported this issue as #8233991.