# Position on Screen Right Bottom

Tags: java, swing, jframe, point, layout-manager

I need to position JFrame on my screen. But I can't make them appear on the right side of the screen bottom.

Please can someone explain me how to position them, if you can describe how to do it, it would be great.

Here is the code so far.

```
    //Gets the screen size and positions the frame left bottom of the screen
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice defaultScreen = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    Rectangle rect = defaultScreen.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
    int x = (int)rect.getMinX();
    int y = (int)rect.getMaxY()- frame.getHeight();
    frame.setLocation(x ,y - 45);
```

Comment: Some platforms limit this, as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2188981/230513).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the example below. Note how [`pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) "Causes this `Window` to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents."

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/q/9753722/230513 */
public class LowerRightFrame {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("LowerRightFrame");
        f.add(new JPanel() {

            @Override // placeholder for actual content
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(320, 240);
            }

        });
        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice defaultScreen = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        Rectangle rect = defaultScreen.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        int x = (int) rect.getMaxX() - f.getWidth();
        int y = (int) rect.getMaxY() - f.getHeight();
        f.setLocation(x, y);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LowerRightFrame().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I know is to nest JPanels each using its own layout manager.

- The main JPanel would use a BorderLayout
- Another JPanel that is added to the main at BorderLayout.SOUTH position also uses BorderLayout.
- the component that needs to go at the SE corner is added to the above JPanel at the BorderLayout.EAST position.
- In general, you're almost always better off using layout managers vs. trying to set absolute position of components.

Comment: yeah! I want to set JFrame. Sorry for misunderstanding! But thanks for trying Pal!

Comment: Just a point of advice for referring to `BorderLayout.SOUTH` and `BorderLayout.EAST`, when we must be using `BorderLayout.PAGE_END` and `BorderLayout.LINE_START` respectively, for jdk 1.4+, as referred by [BorderLayout Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) :-)