# Java Swing background one pixel off on MAC

Tags: java, macos, swing, user-interface

I've created a Java Swing application using the Metal L&F. On Windows, everything looks just fine; but when running the application on a Mac, the background of all the GUI elements seems to be off by one pixel, bleeding out ouf their border to the bootom right.

A checkbox would look like this

[image]

I'd love to provide a code example, but i have no clue where the error could lie, as this behaviour occurs all over the application.

I'd appreciate any hint to the cause of this.

Comment: If you have no clue where the error could lie having the code, how do you expect us to know it without even having the code ? Post a minimalist reproducible example.

Comment: Does this only happen on the Metal L&F?

Comment: Looks OK [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19621050/230513) and [full size](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AnIsF.png).