# Java setFullScreenWindow() keep on top

Tags: java, swing, jframe, fullscreen

I'm writing an application that is intended to be run on a dual monitor setup, with a "Display" JFrame going fullscreen on one monitor and a "Control" JFrame on the other monitor, sending instructions to the Display. I've tried two separate methods of setting the Display fullscreen; the success of each seems to depend on the OS.

```
display.setUndecorated(true);
display.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Works in Windows, but the JFrame gets hidden under the dock/panels in OS X and Linux.

My other method, utilizing

```
GraphicsDevice.setFullScreenWindow(display);
```

Works in all three OSes that I tried, but in Windows, focusing the Control window on the other monitor makes the Display window hide, and calling

```
display.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

Doesn't fix the problem. I'm kind of partial to the `GraphicsDevice` method because I don't have to deal with the issues in OS X or Linux, and I'm hoping that the Windows problem is a simple fix. Is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this...

**For Multiple Screen**

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();


// Get size of each screen

for (int i=0; i<gs.length; i++) {
    DisplayMode dm = gs[i].getDisplayMode();
    int screenWidth = dm.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = dm.getHeight();
}
```

Use `public final void setAlwaysOnTop(boolean alwaysOnTop)` for putting the window on top, If the window is visible, this includes bringing window `toFront`, then "sticking" it to the top-most position.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but what am I supposed to do with the width and height values from that for loop? I tried using `setAlwaysOnTop(true);`, but that didn't work when I tried it. I don't have access to Windows for another hour or so, but I noticed you said "If the window is visible," so maybe I had called that before setting the window visible? I'll try soon and accept your answer if it works.

Comment: Too late to edit my comment...but `setAlwaysOnTop(true);` still doesn't work in Windows. However, I found a workaround in using `System.getProperty("os.name");` to check if the current OS is Windows, so I can instead use the `setExtendedState` method.

Comment: Sorry as it didnt worked for you, but thanks for the info abt the work around....

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows, wich was the solution? I tried to use ´setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)´ but it does not work in some scenarios and when it works, the graphics are not updated.

Comment: This answer is not related in any way with the question. I do not understand how it can be marked as correct and be scored +10

Answer (score 4):

I run across the same problem. My way to solve it was to override the `show()` function in the jframe and by using a [buffer strategy](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) never return out of the show function. Thus something like this:

```
 @override
 public void show(){
        super.show();
        //Create a double buffering strategy
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        while(true){
              //draw our frame
              Graphics g = bs.getGraphics();
              paint(g);
              //dispose of our graphics
              g.dispose();
              //Show our frame
              bs.show();
              try{
                  //Don't use all our cpu-power
                  Thread.sleep(10);
              }catch(Exception e){
                  //Do something (this probably will never happen)
              }
        }
 }
```

It would actually be better if one used `setVisible(boolean)` instead of `show()` (`show` is deprecated). The window won't always be on top (you can still drag another window on top of it), but it won't automatically hide when you give focus to another window. That is the behaviour you want I guess.

**Note:** Do not call `show` in the eventqueue, as this will render the eventqueue useless, and makes the jframe ignore all events. The function `show` should be called in a new thread, then all events will still be handled.