# How do you set your JFame's size to be as big as your computer's screen in java?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, size

I wanted to make a game in java, but i don't know if there is a way to set the size of the JFrame to cover the whole computer screen without actually going and setting the size myself to try to match up with your computer screen size.

P.S I do know how to set the size of the JFrame but i don't know how to make it the same size as my computer screen without trial and error my way through by changing to size over and over again. Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JFrame in full screen Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570356/jframe-in-full-screen-java)

Comment: See this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570356/jframe-in-full-screen-java

Answer (score 1):

To maximize your JFrame you could use

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the size to a value, use `setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)` in `JFrame`.