# Full screen mode in java application

Tags: java, swing

I would like to make an app that have a button that make the app full screen when clicked and then change to normal when the button is clicked second time. The JDK is 1.7 and I know it support application in full screen mode. I tried in many ways but not succeed. Please, is there someone who could help me?

**EDIT1**: I would like to make my app enter and exit "Video Mode Fullscreen". I cannot enter fullscreen on runtime as changing setUndecorated to true on runtime has no effect on appearance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JFrame in full screen Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570356/jframe-in-full-screen-java)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use the [setExtendedState](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState%28int%29) and to set it to [MAXIMIZED_BOTH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#MAXIMIZED_BOTH) as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570356/jframe-in-full-screen-java). It also shows another method to put your Swing Application in real "Video-Mode Fullscreen", if thats what you need.

Comment: I would like to make my app enter and exit "Video Mode Fullscreen". I cannot enter fullscreen on runtime as changing setUndecorated to true on runtime has no effect on appearance.