# expanding JFrame in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, netbeans-8

I tried to resize the window of my JFrame to automatically fit my screen upon running using the following code:

```
private void makeFrameFullSize(JFrame aFrame)
{
 Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
 aFrame.setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
}
```

However, it did not work.
how do I automatically expand the JFrame to fit my size of the screen in NetBeans

Comment: Did you visit previous posts about your problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570356/jframe-in-full-screen-java

Comment: there are no previous posts about this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
private void makeFrameFullSize(JFrame aFrame)
{
   int state = aFrame.getExtendedState();
   aFrame.setExtendedState(stats | Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
}
```

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState-int-