# Make Program Fullscreen JAVA

Tags: java

i want to make my program fullscreen.
I am currently using this code, and its just creating 2 Windows, 1 small one (which the program runs in) and one unclosable window in fullscreen which just opens in the background... 
[This is how it looks:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtuPr.png)
I want my program to be opened in ONE Window in Fullscreen.

```
    jf.setSize(1650,1080);
    jf.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
    jf.setUndecorated(true);
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

What do i need to change? 
Or am i doing something way wrong?

Thanks in advance.

My entire code: (You are now going to realize that i probably have no idea what im doing)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JButton klick, upgrade1, miner1;
    private JTextField punkte;
 static JLabel test;
    private JLabel Pickaxe;
    private JLabel Goldbarren;
    private JLabel minerlbl1;
    public static int minerkosten=200, pickaxekosten=50;
    public static int klicks=0; //Dies ist Ihre Punkzahl.
    int k = 1; //Diese Variable gibt an, wieviel Punkte Sie pro Klick erhalten.
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    {

    }



    public static class Miner extends Thread{
        public void run() {
            while (klicks<1000000000){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                klicks = klicks + 1;
                test.setText("Gold:" + " " + klicks);
            }
        }
    }

    public GUI(){
        this.setSize(1000, 500);
        this.setLocation(250, 200);
        this.setLayout(null);

        jf.setSize(1650,1080);
        jf.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        jf.setUndecorated(true);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        klick = new JButton(new ImageIcon("Goldbarren.png")); //Dies ist der Button den Sie drücken müssen um Punkte zu erhalten.
        klick.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Goldbarren.png")));
        klick.setBorderPainted(false);
        klick.setFocusPainted(false);
        klick.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        klick.setBounds(50, 50, 150, 150);



        upgrade1 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("Pickaxe.png")); //Dies ist der erste Upgrade Button
        upgrade1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Pickaxe.png")));
        upgrade1.setBorderPainted(false);
        upgrade1.setFocusPainted(false);
        upgrade1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        upgrade1.setBounds(200, 200, 150, 150);


        miner1 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images.jpg")); //Dies ist das zweite Upgrade, es sollte pro Sekunde einen Punkt geben.
        miner1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images.jpg")));
        miner1.setBorderPainted(false);
        miner1.setFocusPainted(false);
        miner1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        miner1.setBounds(500, 200, 150, 150);



        //minerlbl1= new JLabel("miner1"); //Dies ist die Beschriftung des zweiten Upgrades.
        minerlbl1= new JLabel("Miner!");
        minerlbl1.setBounds(500, 300, 150, 150);
        minerlbl1.setFont(new Font("Courier new", Font.BOLD, 24));
        minerlbl1.setForeground(Color.BLUE);



        //Pickaxe= new JLabel("Pickaxe"); //Dies ist die Beschriftung des zweiten Upgrades.
        Pickaxe = new JLabel("Pickaxe");
        Pickaxe.setBounds(220, 250, 150, 150);
        Pickaxe.setFont(new Font("Courier new", Font.BOLD, 24));
        Pickaxe.setForeground(Color.BLUE);



        //test= new JLabel("klicks"); //Dieses Label gibt Ihre Anzahl Punkte an.
        test = new JLabel("Points: "+klicks,
                SwingConstants.CENTER);
        test.setBounds(400, 10, 400, 50);
        test.setFont(new Font("Courier new", Font.BOLD, 24));
        test.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

        //Goldbarren= new JLabel("Goldbarren"); //Dies ist die Beschreibung des Goldbarrens
        Goldbarren= new JLabel("Mine!");
        Goldbarren.setBounds(90, 90, 150, 150);
        Goldbarren.setFont(new Font("Courier new", Font.BOLD, 24));
        Goldbarren.setForeground(Color.BLUE);


                punkte = new JTextField(""); //Dies ist das Textfield der Punkte.
        punkte.setBounds(1, 1, 1, 1);
        punkte.setFont(new Font("Courier new", Font.BOLD, 24));
        punkte.setForeground(Color.green);
        punkte.setBackground(Color.white);



        this.add(punkte); //Dies sind die eingefügten Dinge.
        this.add(klick);
        this.add(test);
        this.add(miner1);
        this.add(upgrade1);
        this.add(Pickaxe);
        this.add(Goldbarren);
        this.add(minerlbl1);
        this.setVisible(true);



//Dies sind die ActionListener zu alllen Buttons.
        klick.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

                  klicks += k;
                    test.setText("Gold:" + " " + klicks);


             }
        });



        upgrade1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

                    if (klicks == 50) {
                        upgrade1.setVisible(true);
                    }





                 klicks -= pickaxekosten;
                 test.setText("Gold:" + " " + klicks);
                  k += 1;
                 pickaxekosten = pickaxekosten+4;
             }
             });

        miner1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

                    if (klicks == 200) {
                        upgrade1.setVisible(true);

                    }



                 klicks -= minerkosten;
                 test.setText("Gold:" + " " + klicks);
                 new Miner().start();
                 minerkosten = minerkosten+5;
             }
             });




    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }







public class Start_Klick {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI g=new GUI();


}
```

}

Comment: What is JF? Can you paste the image inside the post rather than link? What framework are you using? Tag your post accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JFrame in full screen Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570356/jframe-in-full-screen-java)

Comment: Please post your code as a (runnable) [mcve].

Comment: I posted my entire code, i hope it helps to understand my mess of a program.

Comment: 2 windows occur because you extend `JFrame` and at the same time you create a new one named `jf`

Comment: Ok i get my mistake, but could you tell me what exactly to change? Pleaseee

Comment: And i cant post the image inside the post, since i need 10 rep to do that.