# Java Window Resolution

Tags: java, swing, jframe, game-engine, java-canvas

I am coding a game in Java.
I just want to know how to make a JFrame window that is fullscreen, but it renders graphics to a canvas that has a smaller resolution from current display.
Example: My pc's current resolution is 1920x1080, and I want my canvas to be 1280x720, and the game to be fullscreen.

Comment: Does [this request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570356/jframe-in-full-screen-java) help you?

Comment: Swing doesn't provide automatic image scaling.  You'll have to determine the size of your canvas and scale your image to fit the available area.