# Make a game full-screen while keeping to scale for any screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I just finished making my first game in Java and want to put my game into fullscreen while keeping the game to scale. I'm using Swing and running the game through a `JFrame`.

How would I go about doing this?

```java
package com.game.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.Serial;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends Canvas{

@Serial
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1478604005915452565L;

public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
    
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    game.start();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570356/jframe-in-full-screen-java might give you a hint about the screen. However,  I think tou are also asking about how to scale the actual content  to fit the screen.  Can you clarify?

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html) may also help.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You posted a bit of code, and told us what you want ... but what exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: This problem is solved with [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). I suggest you read about them and choose the one that will work for your case.