# How to have a JFrame Maximise icon

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How do i create a `JFrame` window in eclipse on a Mac that has an icon that makes the window full screen like the double arrow icon on most windows at the top right??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at

- [Fullscreen feature for Java Apps on OSX Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873568/fullscreen-feature-for-java-apps-on-osx-lion)
- And [Java Runtime System Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Java/Reference/Java_PropertiesRef/Articles/JavaSystemProperties.html), which may be of interested
- or [How can I do full screen in Java on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155838/how-can-i-do-full-screen-in-java-on-osx) if those were the wrong feature you wanted

**UPDATE**

Lucky for you `JFrame` extends `Window` via `Frame`...

[image]

```
public class TestMacFullScreen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                JLabel label = new JLabel("Look ma, no hands");

                frame.add(label);

                enableOSXFullscreen(frame);

                frame.setVisible(true);


            }
        });
    }

    public static void enableOSXFullscreen(Window window) {
        try {
            Class util = Class.forName("com.apple.eawt.FullScreenUtilities");
            Class params[] = new Class[]{Window.class, Boolean.TYPE};
            Method method = util.getMethod("setWindowCanFullScreen", params);
            method.invoke(util, window, true);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like what im looking for (the first one) but im having a bit of trouble implementing it. Im fairly new at java. The function requires a window but how do I get a window from JFrame?

Comment: Thank you for this, My code wasn't working because i had setVisible before calling the fullscreen method. Apparently it needs the window to be hidden to do the operation.

Comment: Wasn't sure, but given my experience with of the other `Window` settings, I figured it would ;)