# Resizing JPanel on OS X

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have two Swing components:
JDialog -> JPanel

I want to fill all space in the JDialog with the JPanel. Default settings work fine. 
I can change size of the dialog and size of JPanel is changed correctly.

But when I click "maximize" icon then inner JPanel is freezed until window will be maximized.

OS X version 10; 
Java version 1.7.

Code example:

```
final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(mainFrame, true);
dialog.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 14));
dialog.add(panel);
dialog.show();
```

Does exist a way to fix this behavior?

Comment: Unrelated : `dialog.show()` , should be `dialog.setVisible(true)`

Answer (score 1):

The following complete example does not freeze when the dialog is resized or maximized. Here are a few things to note:

- The default layout of a `JPanel` is [`FlowLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#flow); for comparison, I've set the frame's layout the same.
- Invoking `pack()` "Causes this `Window` to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents." Since the dialog contains only an empty `Jpanel`, I've overridden [`getPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) to show the effect.
- Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22450263/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(new JLabel("Frame"));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, true);
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(){

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(320, 240);
            }
        };
        panel.add(new JLabel("Dialog"));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 14));
        dialog.add(panel);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution doesn't work. it seems to be OSX specific Java HotSpot bug.

Comment: @Andrew: It works for me under Java 8; also consider the enhancement seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12752503/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054242/230513).